# Why does it take so many steps to add a tag to my favorites?

Tags: discussion

I'm reading some stuff here.  Oooh, a tag on an interesting subject.  I'll add it to my favorites ...

- Click on the tag ...
- It directs me to the page where all the questions related to the tag appears.  That makes sense, but ...
- Search around on the page for the widget that allows me to add the tag to my favorites.
- Back up and go to the main page.
- Nothing here.  Click on my name.
- Ah, favorites, that must be it.  Nooooo ....
- Of course, preferences.  Whew.

What a lot of context shifting from the point of seeing a tag I like to finally adding it as one of my favorites.  [Jakob Nielson](http://www.useit.com/jakob/), where are you?

Answer (score 6):

It's actually pretty easy. See a tag you like in the list of questions, don't click on the question! Just go below the "Ask Question" button, enter it in to the Interesting Questions, and click Add.

[image: Adding a tag]

What'd be nice is if the brand new hover pop-up had an "Add to interesting" or "add to ignored" link.

[image: Popup]

Comment: The *old* hover pop-up had that. I added things to Ignored all the time. \*sigh\*.